# how to calculate mean based on conditions in for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, mean

I have what I think is a simple question but I can't figure it out! I have a data frame with multiple columns. Here's a general example:

```
colony = c('29683','25077','28695','4865','19858','2235','1948','1849','2370','23196')
age = c(21,23,4,25,7,4,12,14,9,7)
activity = c(19,45,78,33,2,49,22,21,112,61)
test.df = data.frame(colony,age,activity)
test.df
```

I would like for R to calculate average activity based on the age of the colony in the data frame. Specifically, I want it to only calculate the average activity of the colonies that are the same age or older than the colony in that row, not including the activity of the colony in that row. For example, colony 29683 is 21 years old. I want the average activity of colonies older than 21 for this row of my data. That would include colony 25077 and colony 4865; and the mean would be (45+33)/2 = 39. I want R to do this for each row of the data by identifying the age of the colony in the current row, then identifying the colonies that are older than that colony, and then averaging the activity of those colonies.

I've tried doing this in a for loop in R. Here's the code I used:

```
test.avg = vector("numeric",nrow(test.df))`
for (i in 1:10){ 
test.avg[i] <- mean(subset(test.df$activity,test.df$age >= age[i])[-i])
}
```

R returns a list of values where half of them are correct and the the other half are not (I'm not even sure how it calculated those incorrect numbers..). The numbers that are correct are also out of order compared to how they're listed in the dataframe. It's clearly able to do the right thing for some iterations of the loop but not all. If anyone could help me out with my code, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your solution is that the index would apply to the original data.frame, yet you subset that and so it does not match anymore.

Try something like this: First find minimum age, then exclude current index and calculate average activity of cases with age >= pre-calculated minimum age.

```r
for (i in 1:10){ 
  test.avg[i] <- {amin=age[i]; mean(subset(test.df[-i,], age >= amin)$activity)}
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, this worked!!!! Thank you so much!! I've been working on this longer than I'd like to admit, but this is exactly what I needed (and I actually understand the logic behind this solution)!!

Answer (score 1):

```r
colony = c('29683','25077','28695','4865','19858','2235','1948','1849','2370','23196')
age = c(21,23,4,25,7,4,12,14,9,7)
activity = c(19,45,78,33,2,49,22,21,112,61)
test.df = data.frame(colony,age,activity)

library(tidyverse)
test.df %>% 
  mutate(result = map_dbl(age, ~mean(activity[age > .x])))
#>    colony age activity   result
#> 1   29683  21       19 39.00000
#> 2   25077  23       45 33.00000
#> 3   28695   4       78 39.37500
#> 4    4865  25       33      NaN
#> 5   19858   7        2 42.00000
#> 6    2235   4       49 39.37500
#> 7    1948  12       22 29.50000
#> 8    1849  14       21 32.33333
#> 9    2370   9      112 28.00000
#> 10  23196   7       61 42.00000

# base
test.df$result <- with(test.df, sapply(age, FUN = function(x) mean(activity[age > x])))
                         
test.df 
#>    colony age activity   result
#> 1   29683  21       19 39.00000
#> 2   25077  23       45 33.00000
#> 3   28695   4       78 39.37500
#> 4    4865  25       33      NaN
#> 5   19858   7        2 42.00000
#> 6    2235   4       49 39.37500
#> 7    1948  12       22 29.50000
#> 8    1849  14       21 32.33333
#> 9    2370   9      112 28.00000
#> 10  23196   7       61 42.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use map_df :

```
  library(tidyverse)
  test.df  %>% 
        mutate(map_df(1:nrow(test.df), ~
                     test.df %>% 
                     filter(age >= test.df$age[.x]) %>% 
                     summarise(av_acti= mean(activity))))
```

Comment: The OP specifically wanted to exclude the activity of the colony in the row for which he is calculating the average activity. You could do something like this in the pipeline: `mutate(test.df, map_df(1:nrow(test.df), ~ test.df %>% mutate(amin = test.df$age[.x]) %>% "["(.,-.x,) %>% filter(age >= amin) %>% summarise(av_acti= mean(activity))))` to get the result he is looking for.